# How programmatically focus a mesh in three js on click on a button?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a three js Mesh on Click of a button the mesh need to be focus based on the button
for example on click of view top camera need to focus from the top of the mesh
in three.js is there any inbuilt method to focus a mesh or how to calculate top left front of a mesh?

```js
var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
var ROTATE = true;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 450 / 450, 0.1, 1000);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.userPan = false;
    controls.userPanSpeed = 0.0;
    controls.maxDistance = 5000.0;
    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.495;
  //  controls.rotateUp(Math.PI * 0.1);
   // controls.autoRotate = ROTATE; //true:自動回転する,false:自動回転しない
    controls.autoRotateSpeed = 4.0; //自動回転する時の速度

    renderer.setSize(465, 465);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = 150;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(100, 100, -100);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
    light.position.set(100, 100, 100).normalize();
    scene.add(light);

    var light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light2.position.set(-100, -100, -100).normalize();
    scene.add(light2);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    var parser = new vox.Parser();
    // yuusha.vox
    parser.parse("https://rawcdn.githack.com/siouxcitizen/3DModel/b2d06e45f6b64c3e342b724a4ec5a0c427a4ce0a/vox/hiyoko.vox").then(function(voxelData) {
        var builder = new vox.MeshBuilder(voxelData, {
            voxelSize: 7.0,
            vertexColor: true,
            optimizeFaces: false,
        });
        var v0 = builder.createMesh();
        v0.position.y -= 50;
        scene.add(v0);
    });
    render();
}

function render() {
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
function topView(){
  alert("topView view") 
}

function sideView(){
  alert("sideview view") 
}

function frontiew(){
  alert("front view") 
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  font: 30px sans-serif;
}
button{
  padding:5px 10px
}
```

```html
<!-- three.min.js r87 -->

<button onClick={topView()}>top view</button>
<button onClick={frontiew()}>front view</button>
<button onClick={sideView()}>side view</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>

<!-- vox.js v1.0.1 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/daishihmr/vox.js@1.0.1/build/vox.min.js"></script>

<!-- Old OrbitControls.js -->
<script src="https://codepen.io/siouxcitizen/pen/XWWXZZN.js"></script>
```

the above is demo code. 
I try to forcefully update camera position it won't work

Answer (score 1):

You can get axis aligned bbox with new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh)
and next - fit camera to this box.
Here is my code (typescript) to do it (works well with PerspetiveCamera and OrbitControls).

```
fitCameraTo(boundingBox: THREE.Box3) {
    const camera = this._camera;
    const objPosition = boundingBox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
    const objSize = boundingBox.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
    boundingBox.min.y = 0;
    boundingBox.max.y = 0;
    const boundingSphere = boundingBox.getBoundingSphere(new THREE.Sphere());

    let dim = boundingSphere.radius * 2;
    if (dim < camera.near) {
        dim = camera.near;
    }

    const direction = THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp.clone(); // view direction

    // object angular size
    const fov = THREE.Math.degToRad(camera.fov);

    let distance = dim / (2.0 * Math.tan(fov / 2.0));

    if (camera.aspect <= 1) {
        distance = distance / camera.aspect;            
    }

    if (distance < camera.near) {
        distance = objSize.y;
    }

    if (distance < camera.near) {
        distance = camera.near;
    }

    camera.position.copy(objPosition.clone().add(direction.multiplyScalar(distance)));

    if (this.this._orbitControls) {
        this._orbitControls.target.copy(objPosition); 
        this._orbitControls.rotateLeft(Math.PI);                        
    } else {
        camera.lookAt(objPosition);
    }

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```